# When clicking HTML button, how do I identify what table row it is being clicked from using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I need to know how to find out which row each button is being clicked from using php. Is this possible?

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['btnDisplay'])) {

        $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_Item";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        print "</br>";
        print "</br>";
        print "</br>";
        print "</br>";

        print '<table style="width:100%">';
        print "<tr>";
            print "<th>ItemID</th>";
            print "<th>Description</th>";
            print "<th>Cost_Price</th>";
            print "<th>Quantity</th>";
            print "<th>Sell_Price</th>";
            print "<th>Image</th>";
            print "<th>Add to cart</th>";
        print "</tr>";

        $costs = array();
            
        for ($i=0; $i < $numRows; $i++) { 

            $sqlSelect =   "SELECT * 
                            FROM tbl_User
                            LIMIT $i,1";

            $result2 = $conn->query($sqlSelect);
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

            array_push($costs, $row['Sell_Price']);

            print "<tr>";
                print "<td>{$row['ItemID']}</td>";
                print "<td>{$row['Description']}</td>";
                print "<td>R{$row['Cost_Price']}</td>";
                print "<td>{$row['Quantity']}</td>";
                print "<td>R{$row['Sell_Price']}</td>";
                print '<td><img src="images/'.$row['ItemID'].'.png" alt="Sorry" style="width:160px;height:96px;"></td>';
                print '<td><input type = "submit" name = "btnAddToCart" value = "Add To Cart" class = "submit"></td>';
            print "</tr>";
        }
        print "</table>";
```

as you can see I have a button called btnDisplay that outputs a table with a bunch of rows of data. There will always be 15 rows each having a button in the final column called btnAddToCart. When btnAddToCart is clicked, I need to know which row it was clicked from using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use a button instead of input. Then you can give it a value different from the text in the button.

```
print "<button type = 'submit' name = 'btnAddToCart' value = '{$row['ItemID']}" class = 'submit'>Add To Cart</button";
```

Then in PHP the value of `$_POST['btnAddToCart']` will be the item ID that they clicked on.

Comment: You're getting in Roomba's way man